# Selectively hiding a HyperLinkField in a gridview in a control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, controls

I have a control which I can call to populate the top of a aspx page with demographic information as follows.

```
<div runat="server" id="headerline" style="width:100%; background-color:#FFFFCC; border-color: #FFFFCC; " >
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" skinID="headerline" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsPatientByID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" >
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="invisible"  />
        <RowStyle Width="100px" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField  DataNavigateUrlFields="PATIENT_ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/demographics/search_demographics.aspx?PatientID={0}" Text="DEMOGRAPHICS   " ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
        </asp:HyperLinkField>
                <ItemTemplate >
                    <asp:Label SkinID="headerline" ID="lblNAME" runat="server" Text=' Name: ' />
                    <asp:Label SkinID="headerline" ID="lblPTNAME" runat="server" Text='<%# Shis.SCR.UI.Common.CapitalisePatientName(Eval("PT_NAME")) %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate >
                    <asp:Label SkinID="headerline" ID="lblDoB" runat="server" Text=' DoB: ' />
                    <asp:Label SkinID="headerline" ID="lblDateofBirth" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("N1_10_DATE_BIRTH") %>' />
                    <asp:Label skinID="headerlineage" ID="lblAge" runat="server" Text='<%# GetDisplayAge("" & Eval("N1_10_DATE_BIRTH"),"" & Eval("L_DEATH_STATUS")) %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate >
                    <asp:Label SkinID="headerline" ID="lblSex" runat="server" Text=' Gender: ' />
                    <asp:Label SkinID="headerline" ID="lblGender" runat="server" Text='<%# EVAL("GENDER") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

I display the demographic data like this and it works fine

```
<div>
    <controls:Demoline id="demoLine1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

What I would like to do is hide the HyperLinkfield when I select a Print option on the page and I get taken to the print page. Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Also add <asp:TemplateField > after </asp:HyperLinkField>. What you've posted isn't valid html

Answer (score 0):

Look into RowDataBound event for the grid, it fires every time a row is bound to the grid. Do you check for a print param, from querystring or where ever and hide hyperlink. On phone so don't have code to hand

Look at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Give your Hyperlink an id eg "MyHyperLink"

add this code:

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["print"] != "1")
            return;

        var link = e.Row.FindControl("MyHyperLink") as HyperLink;
        if (link != null)
            link.Visible = false;
    }
```

and then my add to your asp:GridView element:

```
OnRowDataBound="GridView1_OnRowDataBound"
```